# NetBenas set a breakpoint on each hit from the result list

Tags: java, breakpoints

A large project has some 300 lines `Connections cons = ConnectionsPool.getConnections();` which establish connection with SQL database. I want to quickly see which calls are relevant to the part I am working on. Is there a way to set a breakpoint for each line on the results list, or do I have to do it by hand?

Comment: You could set a breakpoint on the first line of the getConnections method.

Comment: Thank you for advice. This would be an ad-hoc solution for a given situation. Is there a general solution?

Comment: This may help (never used it): http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqDebuggingMethodBreakpoint - although not exactly what you asked for either.

Answer (score 1):

In NetBeans, **Alt + Shift + 5** opens breakpoint menu. From there, when you add a new breakpoint from the breakpoint menu, you can change the breakpoint type to **Method**. From there, you can further define how the breakpoints will be placed, e.g. for all methods in a given class, or for only certain methods.

Comment: Thanks (hence, upvote), this is somewhat relevant, but it doesn't allow to "select all search hits and place a breakpoint against them".